# What is the mempty of the data type?

Tags: haskell

I have following data type with monoid and semigroup instance:

```
newtype Combine a b = 
  Combine { unCombine :: a -> b }

instance (Semigroup b) 
  => Semigroup (Combine a b) where 
  Combine {unCombine=f} <> Combine {unCombine=g} = Combine (f <> g)

instance (Semigroup b, Monoid b)
  => Monoid (Combine a b) where
  mempty = Combine mempty
  mappend = (<>)
```

I want to configure it out, what is the `mempty` value of the function`(->)`?

I've tried for example:

```
*Exercises Data.Monoid> mempty :: (-> Integer Bool)
<interactive>:21:15: error: parse error on input `Integer'
```

How does the implementation of `mempty` in `monoid` looks like?

I looked at hackage source:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
        mempty _ = mempty
        mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

and can not find the implementation of `mempty`.

Maybe to clarify what I mean, consider following example:

```
*Exercises Data.Monoid> mempty :: (Product Integer)
Product {getProduct = 1}
```

The mempty of `Product Integer` is `Product {getProduct = 1}`.

Comment: With the built-in `Monoid` instance for functions `Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)`, `const mempty`, since `mappend f g` is `\x -> mappend (f x) (g x)`.

Comment: to elaborate on the previous comment, `(f<>g) x = f x <> g x`; since `f<>mempty` must be `== f` by Monoid laws (and `mempty<>f == f`, too), we have `(f<>mempty) x = f x <> mempty x` == `f x <> mempty = f x <> (const mempty) x`. thus for functions into a Monoid, `mempty = const mempty`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The type constructor `(->)` isn't a type constant (there aren't any values of type `(->)`), and therefore can't have a monoid instance.
2. If the type `b` has a monoid instance, the type constant `a -> b` (or `(->) a b`) does have a monoid instance and `mempty` yields a function, which ignores its inputs and returns `mempty` of `b` as value.

If you look at

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
    mempty _ = mempty
    mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

the line `mempty _ = mempty` implements this.

What is the type of `mempty` for `a -> b`? It is `a -> b`, as `mempty` needs to be a value of type `a -> b`. So

`mempty _ = mempty`

tells us , that `mempty` for `a -> b` is a function, which discards its input and returns **`mempty`**, **a value of type `b`**. The two occurrences of the name `mempty` in this definition **refer to different** functions/values.

Let's hit some concrete examples:

1. You tried

   ```
   mempty :: (-> Integer Bool)
   ```

   that is syntactically wrong. You wanted to try

   ```
   mempty :: (->) Integer Bool
   ```

   which yields a new error

   ```
   <interactive>:5:1: error:
      • No instance for (Monoid Bool) arising from a use of ‘mempty’
      • In the expression: mempty :: (->) Integer Bool
        In an equation for ‘it’: it = mempty :: (->) Integer Bool
   ```

   as `Bool` doesn't have a monoid instance.
2. You tried

   ```
   mempty :: (Product Integer)
   ```

   which worked and yielded `Product {getProduct = 1}` as value.
   That tells you, that `Product Integer` has a monoid instance. Therefore we *could* try having `Product Integer` as type **`b`** in `a -> b`.
3. Now try

   ```
   > let f = mempty :: a -> Product Integer
   > f 'x'
   Product {getProduct = 1}
   ```

   In this example `mempty` refers to some value of type `a -> Product Integer` and therefore is a function. So the type variable `t` from `mempty :: (Monoid t) => t` refers to the type  `a -> Product Integer` in this case.

Comment: Why does the `mempty` for function(->) has an argument? When I look at the type of signature of  `mempty`, it has no arguement `mempty :: Monoid a => a`.

Comment: What do you mean with `(->) isn't a type constant`? Isn't type constant just another term for nullary cons? I think `(->)` cannot have a monoid instance because it has the wrong kind: `* -> * -> *`. @zero_coding: What do you think is `a` in the function instance?

Comment: I thought `type constant` refer to nullary `type constructors` that is type constructors of kind `*`. But I checked the haskell report and it mentions `type constant` only twice, so I am unsure, wethet thats widely used anymore.

Comment: @ftor Look at the `mempty :: Monoid a => a` definition, it does expect any argument but if you look at `(a -> b)` monoid instance, `mempty` expects an parameter. Why?

Comment: @zero_coding `mempty :: Monoid a => a` is the generic type signature. For the function instance `a` is `a -> b` (where `b` must be a monoid). Hence the type sig for this instance is `mempty :: Monoid b => a -> b` and `a` is the argument you're looking for.

Comment: Why `b` has to be a monoid, because of closed type?

Comment: `b` has to be a monoid, because only in this case, there is a monoid instance for `a -> b`.